# How to pick the highest point in DC.JS scatterplot using brush

Tags: dc.js

I'm using DC.JS scatterplots to let users select points of interest.  If you use elastic axis you cannot select the highest value point.  Look at the DC.JS example (https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter-brushing.html).  You cannot select the highest point in the left or right plot.

In several cases, the highest or lowest point(s) is exactly what people need to be able to select because those are the outliers we care about.  If you disable elastic axis and make sure you specify a range that is higher than the max value, you can select the point.

Is there another solution besides setting the axis domain based on current min/max and expanding them little bit?  This is sometimes ugly when the minimum=0 and now your domain needs to include some small negative number.

--Nico

Comment: Padding should help but it's applied on both sides equally, as you allude. Related issue: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always when I face this issue, I increase the y domain by 5% manually.
For instance:

```
var balanceDomain = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, s.balanceDimension.top(1)[0].balance + (s.balanceDimension.top(1)[0].balance*0.05)]);

s.amountOverallScore
    .width(400)
    .height(400)
    .x(someDomain)
    .y(balanceDomain)
    ...
```

Maybe this is not the best solution, but always work for me.
Hope it helps (=.

Comment: Hi Roger,  Thanks for the suggestion.   Works great.  I'll mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my application the values were always positive and I used the following to get correct behavior:

```
// using reductio on the all_grp to get easy access to filtered min,max,avg,etc.
totalTimeMinValue = all_grp.top(1)[0].value.min;
totalTimeMaxValue = all_grp.top(1)[0].value.max;    

// now use it to scale the charts we want
detail1_chart.y(d3.scale.linear().domain([totalTimeMinValue-1, totalTimeMaxValue+1]));
detail3_chart.y(d3.scale.linear().domain([totalTimeMinValue-1, totalTimeMaxValue+1]));
```

This keeps both charts in sink.  An additional benefit was that my rather large dots (symbolsize=15) are no longer being clipped.

Thanks Roger.